# Do not create Complex type in WSDL from C# class

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I need to create a web service and generate the corresponding WSDL file.
I need to provide a list of fields related to a customer, such the name, the address and so on.

The problem is I need to keep them in the body of the WSDL without generating a complex type, but I would like to wrap all these fields in the `Customer` class.

Is there a way not to generate the complex type from a class, and tell to just consider its variables? Googling around I always found the opposite question!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To explain it a little bit better, my WSDL should have a similar snippet:

```
<pos:NAME>?</pos:NAME>
<pos:SURNAME>?</pos:SURNAME>
<pos:ADDRESS>?</pos:ADDRESS>      
<pos:OTHER_DATA>?</pos:OTHER_DATA>
<pos:OTHER_DATA2>?</pos:OTHER_DATA2>
<pos:OTHER_DATA3>?</pos:OTHER_DATA3>
```

I would like to create a "Customer" class in my code for better code management, without the risk of generating something like:

```
  <pos:CUSTOMER>
        <pos:NAME>?</pos:NAME>
        <pos:SURNAME>?</pos:SURNAME>
        <pos:ADDRESS>?</pos:ADDRESS>
   </pos_CUSTOMER>
   <pos:OTHER_DATA>?</pos:OTHER_DATA>
   <pos:OTHER_DATA2>?</pos:OTHER_DATA2>
   <pos:OTHER_DATA3>?</pos:OTHER_DATA3>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to do. A WSDL by its very definition among other things  is the description of the data at the service end point. You can't modify the structure of the data from the end point without changing the service. Seems like you need to write an adapter to map the data from the end point to your customer class.

Comment: I was given a document to implement my WebService and the resulting WSDL, where in the body I have customer data plus some other infos. In my code I just would like to write a Customer class without it resulting in a complex type in my WSDL.

Comment: The web service needs to return either a simple or complex type so the consuming client can serialize the data when the response comes back in. Perhaps you could create a simple web method that simply returns a pipe delimited string. You could then transpose that into your Customer class.

Comment: I edited the question to better explain what I mean.

Comment: I do understand what you mean. Lets imagine that there is a web service that exposes a method called "GetCustomer" and you expect the response to contain the fields Name, Surname etc... what type would you expect the result returned to the client to be?   I not an expert on Web services but i can't think of a way to return complex data without a complex type? Maybe someone else will educate us :)

Comment: Q:? Why are you not allowed to have a complex type in your WSDL?

Comment: It's not "my" WSDL: there has been an agreement between 2 systems, I must develop using the analysis document that contains the required fields and hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry.. at the top it says "I need to create a web service and generate the corresponding WSDL file". I thought you were developing a web service and then generating the WSDL for use in the client to consume!

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I'm forced to generate the WSDL within certain limitations! :D

Comment: Well you can't encapsulate customer data in a class in a web service and have the service return that class, but have the WSDL describe a different interface. WSDL is exactly this... Web Services Description Language. Sorry...dont think it can be done. Do let me know if someone else posts otherwise. Cheers